# Can anybody tell me the regex that matches twenty (20) day and 28 days but not in 27 days

Tags: python-3.x, regex, nlp

I am writing a python script to match the duration of an activity. There are 2 choices- X days/months/years or  (X) days/months/years.

I wrote a regex `\w*\s*['(']*\d{1,4}[')']*\s*\w{3,6}` and the sentence is

```
Ujjwal in 28 days and 40 months and 2 years or twenty (20) day
```

I want to match only `28 days`, `40 months`, `2 years` and `twenty (20) day`.

But my regex is matching `in 28 days`, `and 40 months`, `and 2 years`.

Please help me.

Comment: Please use right tool for the job - regex isn't it. You can use microscope to hammer nails too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easier to be more specific with your regex, trying to match either a word before digits in parentheses or just digits:

```
(?:\w+\s+\(\d+\)|\b\d+)
```

followed by a space and one of the date type words:

```
\s+(?:year|month|day)s?
```

In python:

```py
import re

text = 'Ujjwal in 28 days and 40 months and 2 years or twenty (20) day'
print(re.findall(r'(?:\w+\s+\(\d+\)|\b\d+)\s+(?:year|month|day)s?', text))
```

Output:

```py
['28 days', '40 months', '2 years', 'twenty (20) day']
```